# Cygwin sub-directories different color than files

Tags: cygwin, color-scheme

In Cygwin I have the xterm color scheme, which is nice, but I don't like that it colors directories and files the same, i.e. when you do `ls` and it displays the contents of a directory with sub-directories and files, everything is colored white. What I would like is to have the sub-directories colored something else, e.g. blue, like I have on my Ubuntu machine, so I can easily distinguish which ones are directories. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

run this command

```
alias ls="ls --color=auto"
```

to make it permanent

add this to your `~/.bashrc` file